# Beeswarm with logarithmic X axis

Tags: r, scatter-plot, beeswarm

I am trying to plot a "beeswarm" which is essentially a single-dimensional scatterplot

```
library(beeswarm)
data(breast)
beeswarm(breast$time_survival,horizontal=TRUE)
```

What I want to achieve is logarithmic transformation of the X axis.

Obviously, I can do `beeswarm(log(breast$time_survival),horizontal=TRUE,method="hex")` but it plots logarithmically transformed data and X axis no longer reperesents survival time numerically. Is there a way to directly affect the X axis? In regular scatterplot, I would do `plot(breast$time_survival,log="x")` but not sure how to behave with `beeswarm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option for beeswarm is log=TRUE, not log="x"

```
library(beeswarm)
data(breast)
beeswarm(breast$time_survival,horizontal=TRUE, log=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. when I do that, with my real data the X axis numeric values appear like this`5.00E-01
1.00E+00
5.00E+00
1.00E+01
5.00E+01
1.00E+02
5.00E+02
1.00E+03
` .  These are essentially the numbers ranging from 0.5 to 1000. How can I make them appear in the proper numeric format? Sorry for not having the actual data for that.

Comment: It looks like your original question was answered. The appropriate wy to show thanks is not by typing it in a comment, but by upvoting answer and selecting it if it is the best answer.  If you have a separate question about how to format axis labels in integer rather than scientific notation, consider asking a new question.  Comments are not the right way to ask new questions, because no-one else will find the answers buried there. But do your own research first before asking this question, you will almost find it already answered.